# Embed a Webcam URL in HTML and be able to view in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webcam, browser-addons

I have a webcam (Dlink 942L.)

The HTML code is listed in the comment below. (see comment below)
1. I am able to view the webcam in firefox but not in chrome. What should I do in order to be able to view also in Chrome?

2. How do I embed the user password of the Dlink 942L camera in the URL, i  order to stream the video without having to enter the user account everytime?

My main goal is to be able to view the webcam within my website by adding HTML code, so users from both Chrome/Mozilla be able to view the webcam video streaming within my website.

Comment: Please see this tutorial, this may help you. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: <div style="text-align: center;">
                <img id="mjpgImage" alt="Processing..." src="http://WebCamIp:80/video/mjpg.cgi" >
                </img>
</div>